# How to invoke a composite type

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

I want to know how to invoke a composite type with Npgsql, I'm using vb.
This would be the code, starting with the type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.type_detalle_ac AS
(
  id_componente integer,
  precio numeric(10,2),
  cantidad integer,
  sub_total numeric(10,2)
);
```

this would be the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_adm_artefacto(
v_serie character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_tipo_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_modelo character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_marca integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_detalle type_detalle_ac DEFAULT NULL::type_detalle_ac,
v_usuario integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_id_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_tipo_operacion character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 0
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 

    VL_ID_ARTEFACTO INTEGER;
    VL_ID_DETALLE_AC INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF V_TIPO_OPERACION = 'I' THEN

        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID_ARTEFACTO),0) INTO VL_ID_ARTEFACTO FROM ARTEFACTO;
        VL_ID_ARTEFACTO:=VL_ID_ARTEFACTO+1;

        INSERT INTO ARTEFACTO (ID_ARTEFACTO,SERIE,TIPO_ARTEFACTO,MODELO,MARCA,USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        VALUES (VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,v_serie,v_tipo_artefacto,v_modelo,v_marca,V_USUARIO,NOW());

        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID_DETALLE_AC),0) INTO VL_ID_DETALLE_AC FROM DETALLE_AC;
        VL_ID_DETALLE_AC:=VL_ID_DETALLE_AC+1;

        INSERT INTO DETALLE_AC(ID_DETALLE_AC,ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,
                               USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        SELECT VL_ID_DETALLE_AC,VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW()
        FROM (SELECT V_DETALLE.*) AS V_DETALLE;
        --VALUES (VL_ID_DETALLE_AC,VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,V_DETALLE.ID_COMPONENTE,V_DETALLE.PRECIO,V_DETALLE.CANTIDAD,V_DETALLE.SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW());


    END IF;

END;


$BODY$;
```

now in vb, starting with the class code:

```
Public Class E_DETALLE_AC
   Public Property id_componente As Integer

   Public Property precio As Decimal
   Public Property cantidad As Integer
   Public Property sub_total As Decimal
End Class
```

I am trying to invoke it in the following way with MapCompositeGlobally, but I can not:

```
Sub ADMINISTRAR_ARTEFACTO(ByVal P As E_ARTEFACTO, ByVal LD As List(Of E_DETALLE_AC))
    NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally(Of List(Of E_DETALLE_AC))("type_detalle_ac")
    Dim CONECTION As New NpgsqlConnection


    Try
        CONECTION.ConnectionString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=123;Database=ALURHE_DB"
        Dim COMMAND As New NpgsqlCommand
        With COMMAND
            .Connection = CONECTION
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "SP_ADM_ARTEFACTO"

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_serie", P.P_SERIE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_tipo_artefacto", P.P_TIPO_ARTEFACTO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_modelo", P.P_MODELO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_marca", P.P_MARCA)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_detalle", LD)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_usuario", P.P_USUARIO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_id_artefacto", If(P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M", P.P_ID_ARTEFACTO, DBNull.Value))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_tipo_operacion", P.P_TIPO_OPERACION)

            End With


        CONECTION.Open()

        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CONECTION.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            CONECTION.Close()
        End If

        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

> PostgreSQL composite type public.type_detalle_ac contains field id_componente which could not match any on CLR type List`1

What I can do ? Npgsql supports a list ?

Comment: Your PostgreSQL type is called "type_detalle_ac", but your CLR type is called E_DETALLE_AC - there's no reason to expect Npgsql to connect them together...

Comment: You can simply pass the name of the PostgreSQL composite as a string parameter to your `MapCompositeGlobally()` call.

Comment: I have modified it like this: NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally (Of List (Of E_DETALLE_AC)) ("type_detalle_ac")

Comment: but I get the following error: PostgreSQL composite type public.type_detalle_ac contains field component_id which could not match any on CLR type List`1

Comment: Well that's a bit of progress... However, your PostgreSQL composite type above mentions `id_componente` rather than `component_id`, are you sure you're posting the right code?

Comment: Sorry, the correct message is: PostgreSQL composite type public.type_detalle_ac contains field id_componente which could not match any on CLR type List`1

Comment: What I can do ? I'll appreciate your answer

Comment: Hi, I have been modifying the code and I have modified the question, but I get an error when I use a list

Comment: It's really to understand... Is the regular composite working now? Which list are you using? What error are you getting? It's hard to help you with such partial information...

Comment: it works, if I only send the class: NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally (Of E_DETALLE_AC) ("type_detalle_ac"). But it does not work, if I send a list of that class: NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally (Of List (Of E_DETALLE_AC)) ("type_detalle_ac") .. I need to send a table

Comment: When I try to send the list, it gives me the following error message: PostgreSQL composite type public.type_detalle_ac contains field id_componente which could not match any on CLR type List`1

Comment: hello, I have created a new question ,,, do you know if it is possible to pass a table?